# How can I get R to display full date in chron package

Tags: r

```
unique(as.character(dates(index(rainfall)))[which(rainfall>QUANTILES[1,1])])
```

the result displayed is this "99-10-22" but I would like to get "1999-10-22"

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

as.Date("99-10-22","%y-%m-%d") would give you the required output.

Comment: this date that I put is just one example as there is much more data in the file and the output is big so I cannot type for each date separately what you write here.